# how upgrade ubuntu 16.04 to 20.04 without Internet access

Tags: 16.04, server, do-release-upgrade, offline

How can I upgrade Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS without Internet access?

Comment: Due to the huge changes between the releases any "upgrade" is strongly discouraged. Instead do your backups and the install from scratch with the installation/live media.

Comment: There is also no direct upgrade path. You need to update to 18.04 first and from there to 20.04.

Comment: You can *upgrade via reinstall* desktop systems rather easily; though to re-install your additional *manually-installed* packages an internet connection is required (*internet is required to download packages not found on the ISO/install media; if internet isn't detected this re-install manually-installed packages step is skipped & error given instead*). You've tagged *server* though where it's less useful.

Comment: @pLumo<br/>When I run the sudo do-release-upgrade  in the command line environment, it connects to the Internet. And the problem is that my server is not connected to the Internet. If you have a solution, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Skipping over releases as you are trying to do is generally regarded as a bad package management decision and discouraged, especially if you don't have an internet connection. You should also think about whether Ubuntu 22.04 LTS would be a better choice for you than Ubuntu 20.04 LTS because it's newer and better. This is an ideal opportunity for you to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04. If you don't have an internet connection don't select the options to download updates and third-party software when installing Ubuntu.

Comment: .I access the Ubuntu server from the command line environment. Is there a solution to update the version, please let me know

Comment: [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/q/34430/) and [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/)

Comment: I read the links you sent but it did not help

Comment: Try a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.